# How to compute a probability threshold for a linear combination of two variables ~ N(0,1)?

Tags: normal-distribution

I have a variable which is a linear combination of two other variables, each one following an N(0,1) distribution.

I need to compute the threshold of the distribution of this combination variable (to compute the Z for a specific probability).

Does anyone know which function should I use, i.e. which package is available to perform this task?

Comment: I think you should update your title to reflect the fact that you're looking for a quantile (given a probability value) rather than a probability value. (If I understand the body of your question correctly.)

Answer (score 3):

If you know what the coefficients in the linear combination, and the two random variables are independent, this is simple.  We have:

$$X=a_1Z_1+a_2Z_2\sim N\left(0,\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2}\right)$$

This is an elementary statistics result, and can be shown by the method of characteristic functions, or convolutions (and other methods...).  So you can use a normal tables, and any statistical package has normal tables - take your pick.  For example, in excel you can use norm.inv(...), in R you can use qnorm(..), in SAS you can use QUANTILE("NORMAL",..) etc. etc.

Comment: In fact, the same method works if $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are jointly normal with correlation coefficient $\rho$ (instead of being independent) with the minor twist that now $$X=a_1Z_1+a_2Z_2\sim N\left(0,\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2 +2\rho a_1a_2}\right).$$  Of course, $\rho = 0$ if $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are independent and so the bells-and-whistles formula given above simplifies to the one given in probabilityislogic's answer in this special case.