# Covariance matrix for a linear combination of correlated Gaussian random variables

Tags: correlation, normal-distribution, covariance-matrix

Supposing $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with a joint bivariate normal distribution and covariance matrix $\Sigma_{XY}$. Consider the following linear combination for constants $A$, $B$ and $C$:

$$Z = AX + BY + C$$

[This Cross Validated post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22879/linear-combination-of-two-dependent-multivariate-normal-random-variables) states that $Y$ will be normally distributed according to:

$$
AX+BY+C \sim \mathcal{N}\left[ 
\left(\begin{matrix}A& B \end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}\mu_X\\\mu_Y\end{matrix}\right) + C, 
\left(\begin{matrix}A & B \end{matrix}\right)\Sigma_{X,Y} \left(\begin{matrix}A^T \\ B^T \end{matrix}\right)\right]
$$

However I would like to know how to compute the covariance matrix $\Sigma_{X,Y,Z}$. How can I calculate the correlation between the new variable $Z$ and the old variables $X$ and $Y$ i.e. $corr(Z,X)$ and $corr(Z,Y)$?

Comment: For those formulas to be true, should be "...with *covariance* matrix $\Sigma_{XY}$, not correlation matrix.

Comment: Correct. I have edited it.

Comment: @MatthewGunn Even with the change you have suggested, the formulas are correct only as far as the mean and variance are concerned, but the $\mathcal N (\cdot, \cdot)$ part is not correct unless one makes the _stronger_ assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are _jointly_ normal. See whuber's comment on Xi'an's answer in the thread referenced by the OP..

Comment: @DilipSarwate I did not appreciate that. This [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674161/are-any-linear-combination-of-normal-random-variables-normally-distributed) explains it fairly well. So only linear combinations of independent normal variables are guaranteed to be normal. If they are correlated this is no longer the case. So I will edit my post to include the stronger assumption that X and Y are jointly normal.

Comment: "So only linear combinations of independent normal variables are guaranteed to be normal. If they are correlated this is no longer the case." is incorrect. Independence is in no way required. Linear combinations of random variables whose joint distribution is multivariate normal will follow the normal distribution (indeed, this is one way to define the multivariate normal distribution). Bivariate normal distribution is a special case of the multivariate normal distribution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are *correlated* (univariate) normal random variables and $Z = AX+BY+C$,  then the linearity of expectation and the bilinearity of the covariance function gives us that

\begin{align}
E[Z] &= AE[X] + BE[Y] + C,\tag{1}\\
\operatorname{cov}(Z,X) &= \operatorname{cov}(AX+BY+C,X) = A\operatorname{var}(X) + B\operatorname{cov}(Y,X)\\
\operatorname{cov}(Z,Y) &= \operatorname{cov}(AX+BY+C,Y) = B\operatorname{var}(Y) + A\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)\\
\operatorname{var}(Z) &= \operatorname{var}(AX+BY+C) \quad = A^2\operatorname{var}(X) + B^2\operatorname{var}(Y) + 2AB \operatorname{cov}(X,Y), \tag{2}\\
\end{align}
but it is *not* necessarily true that $Z$ is a *normal* (a.k.a Gaussian)
random variable.  That $X$ and $Y$ are *jointly* normal random variables
is *sufficient* to assert that $Z = AX+BY+C$ is a normal random variable.
Note that $X$ and $Y$ are not required to be independent; they can be
correlated as long as they are *jointly* normal. For examples of
normal random variables $X$ and $Y$ that are *not* jointly normal
and yet their sum $X+Y$ is normal, see the answers to 
*[Is joint normality a
necessary condition for the sum of normal random variables to 
be normal?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/189130/6633)*. As pointed out at the end of my own answer there, joint normality means that
*all* linear combinations $aX+bY$ are normal, whereas in the special
case being discussed there, only *one* linear combination
$X+Y$ of non-jointly normal random variables is proven to be normal; most other linear combinations are not normal.

More generally, if $X$ and $Y$ are (column) $n$-vector random variables with $n\times n$ covariance matrices $\Sigma_{X,X}$, $\Sigma_{Y,Y}$,
and $n\times n$ crosscovariance matrix $\Sigma_{X,Y}$,
$A$ and $B$ are $m\times n$ nonrandom matrices, and $Z$ and $C$ (column)
$m$-vectors, then it is indeed true that
\begin{align} E[Z] &= AE[X] + BE[Y] + C &\quad \scriptstyle{\text{compare with } (1)}\\
\Sigma_{Z,Z} &= A\Sigma_{X,X}A^T + B\Sigma_{Y,Y}B^T +2A\Sigma_{X,Y}B^T
&\quad \scriptstyle{\text{compare with } (2)}\\
\end{align}
but, as in the univariate case, it is not necessarily true that
$Z$ is a normal vector (in the sense that the $m$ components $Z_i$
are *jointly* normal random variables). Once again, joint
normality of $(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n, Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_n)$
suffices to allow the assertion that $Z$ is a normal random vector.

Comment: Great answer. The formulas for $cov(Z,X)$ and $cov(Z,Y)$ were what I was looking for. They give the same values that I obtained for covariance by doing Monte Carlo simulation in Matlab and recording sample covariance.

Answer (score 2):

Covariance matrix $\Sigma_{xy}$ can be written:
$$ \Sigma_{xy} = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} c_{xx} & c_{xy} \\ c_{yx} & c_{yy}  \end{array} \right] $$

Where $c_{ab}$ denotes the covariance between $a$ and $b$. (Note symmetric so $c_{ab} = c_{ba}$.)

The covariance matrix for $X$,$Y$, and $Z$ would be:
$$ \Sigma_{xyz} = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} c_{xx} & c_{xy} & c_{xz} \\ c_{yx} & c_{yy} & c_{yz} \\ c_{zx} & c_{zy} & c_{zz} \\  \end{array} \right] $$

You need to find the additional terms:

$$\begin{align*}
c_{zx} &= E[(Z - E[z])(X - E[x])] = \quad ?\\
c_{zy} &= E[(Z - E[z])(Y - E[y])] = \quad ?\\
c_{zz} &= E[(Z - E[z])^2]  = \quad ?\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: That's my question. How can $c_{zx}$ and $c_{zy}$ be calculated?

Comment: @Jack Pierce-Brown Apply the properties of covariance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Properties .