# How to show via Delta method that the Linear Taylor series expansion of a normal random vector results in NORMAL DISTRIBUTION

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable, delta-method

How can it be proved using the delta method that the Linear Taylor series expansion of a normal random vector containing independent but NOT identically distributed elements results in a random variable whose distribution is approximately normal?

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what you mean by "the Linear Taylor series expansion of a normal random vector"? Ordinarily one would expand a given *function* of a random variable in a Taylor series, but you haven't put any such function in evidence.

Comment: Indeed, I mean the Taylor series expansion of a function of random variables where we truncate the series to include only the linear terms, meaning the first two terms.

Comment: So would it be fair to interpret your question as asking why a linear combination of a multivariate normal is normal?

Comment: Yes. Indeed, but in this case the function is not just Y = AX+B but in fact the first order Taylor series is given by Y=g(X) = g(mu_x)+[X-mu_x] dg(X)/dX (assuming that X is a univariate random variable). For this linear approximation is Y normal if X is a normally distributed random vector with independent but not identically distributed elements?

Comment: By *definition,* the first order Taylor series is a linear function. You merely have $B=g(\mu_X) - \mu_x dg/dx$ and $A=dg/dx$, each of which is a *number*.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. But how can I prove that this linear combination is also normal?

Comment: Search our site on [normal linear combination](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=normal+linear+combination)  For the gory details see http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/19953/919.