# The product of 3 lognormals coming from tri-variate normal distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, lognormal-distribution

My question is similar to this one [The product of two lognormal random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/212690/the-product-of-two-lognormal-random-variables), but I'd like to do it with three lognormals. The referenced question cannot be applied twice since the correlation between $X_1X_2$ and $X_3$ is not known.

Let $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ be three normal random variables. Write $X_1\sim N(\mu_1, \sigma^2_1)$, $X_2\sim N(\mu_2, \sigma^2_2)$ and $X_3\sim N(\mu_3, \sigma^3_2)$. The tri-variate normal distribution $(X,Y,Z)$ has a correlation structure with $\rho(X_1,X_2)=\rho_{X_1X_2}$, $\rho(X_1,X_3)=\rho_{X_1X_3}$ and $\rho(X_2,X_3)=\rho_{X_2X_3}$.

Consider the corresponding log-normal random variables: $Z_1 = \exp(X_1)$, $Z_2 = \exp(X_2)$ and $Z_3 = \exp(X_3)$.

Question: what is the distribution of the product of the three random variables, i.e., the distribution of $Z_1Z_2Z_3$?

It's easy to compute the distributions of $Z_1Z_2$ using the referenced question, but I'm stuck because I don't know the correlation between $X_1X_2$ and $X_3$.

Comment: Just apply the referenced answer twice.  Note that it requires only the correlations among the $X_i,$ not among the $Z_i.$

Comment: @whuber But how do you get the correlation between $X_1X_2$ and $X_3$?

Comment: That's irrelevant, because $\log(Z_1Z_2Z_3)=X_1+X_2+X_3,$ not $X_1X_2+X_3.$  The whole point of the duplicate is that $X_1+X_2+X_3$ has a Normal distribution and so $Z_1Z_2Z_3$ has the corresponding lognormal distribution.