# Confusion about two Gaussian distributions

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, joint-distribution, gaussian-mixture-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution

1. From [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/428058/is-the-joint-distribution-of-two-linear-combinations-of-gaussians-still-a-multiv?noredirect=1&lq=1), it says that, linear combination of two Gaussian distribution, are always Gaussians.
2. However, Let  be standard normal and =±1 with probability 1/2 each, independently of . Let =. Then  is also standard normal, but =+ is exactly equal to zero with probability 1/2 and is equal to 2 with probability 1/2.

But (2) contradicts with (1). Am I missing anythings?

Comment: 1 is incorrect as a general statement,  unless the two have a bivariate/multivariate Gaussian distribution.  This point is discussed in the answers and comments on your linked question

Comment: Henry's comment is true but, also, even if the assumption does hold,  you're creating a degenerate case for half of the distribution by adding X to -X so there is no distribution but a point mass at zero. So, it's not really a contradiction, atleast to me. When they talk about linear combinations of normals, they are referring to linear combinations of DIFFERENT normals rather than the same one.